# options for blocking ads

Tags: midori

I love the design aesthetics of midori (well, the whole OS, really), but I can't bear the thought of being exposed to the gamut of online ads.

Does anyone have any suggestion on ad blocking?

I've read in the past about the possibility of ad-blocking in Windows through the "hosts" file, does similar exist for elementary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings --> preferences --> Extensions

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Click on the configuration icon on right side, select preferences.

[image: Imgur]

Also possible to go those sites and add even more block lists. But these two (EasyPrivacy and EasyList) should be enough to block most of the common ads.